# Symfony 2.8 with Oracle Database - Identifier is too long

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to configure phpcr_odm with Symfony 2.8 using Oracle database from 
this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/1.3/cmf/bundles/phpcr_odm/introduction.html). When I'm trying to run `php app/console doctrine:schema:create` my console returns error

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
  An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_37E65615460D9FD7413BC13C1AC10DC4E7087E10 ON phpc
  r_binarydata (node_id, property_name, workspace_name, idx)':
  ORA-00972: identifier is too long
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\OCI8Exception]
  ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```

I know that Oracle SQL limits unique indexes for 30 chars but I don't know how to limit unique indexes before they are executed in symfony. Can somebody please tell me how to fix this issue  ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

If you declare the unique constraint on your entity yourself you can set its name manually:

```
@ORM\Table(name="phpcr_binarydata", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="SMALL_KEY_NAME_HERE", columns={"node_id", "property_name", "workspace_name", "idx"})})
```

If the database creation is not under your control the maximum identifier length is configured in `Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaConfig::$maxIdentifierLength` which you could try to extend and override.

Comment: 'phpcr_binarydata' is not table created by me , i found that jackalope vendor is using this table so I don't think that i can create unique constraint for this unique index

Answer (score 0):

In SQL-92 the later version of the standard appears to optionally allow for 128 character names. Otherwise this would be the solution: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/AbstractAsset.php#L219